# Angular dependency missing from git

Tags: javascript, angularjs, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

We'r developing an app in Steroids Supersonic framework (Based on Angular designed for Native apps). The team before us added following two dependencies which giving problems when we try to install all the dependencies using bower.

"angular-ui-laicos": "git@github.com:Laicos/angular-ui-laicos.git",
"appgyver": "git@github.com:Laicos/appgyver.git",

Both of git repositories are not there, so what kind of alternative would be used for this case? In the project at many places both dependencies are being used.

Comment: Doesn't the Steroid Supersonic framework already provide support for AngularJS? What are these optional libraries supposed to do?

Comment: That's the problem, no doubt Supersonic provide support itself, it's confusing why the old team used these components

<script src="/components/angular-ui-laicos/angular-ui-laicos.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/Laicos.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/console/Console.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/view/View.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/ActionSheet.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/Share.js"></script>
<script src="/components/appgyver/view/Scrolltastic.js"></script>

Comment: maybe you should ask the old team then :-) - It might me that at the time the Angular support wasn't part of Steroid Supersonic and it has been added just recently.